# How can I get my php form working correctly?

Tags: php, form-submit

I built a form for my website using php. After the form is submitted, the content is emailed to me and the user is redirected to a different page. The code works fine when I fill the form out completely. However, one of the fields is a file upload and when I don't upload anything, the form still sends but leads to a 500 internal server error page. How can I make it so the form still redirects to the right page when a file isn't uploaded? I included my code below

```
<?php
$email_to = "ashley@MyURL.com";
$email_subject = "Completed Questionnaire";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gradyear = $_POST['gradyear']; 
$hschool = $_POST['hschool']; 
$hometown = $_POST['hometown'];
$email_from = $_POST['email']; 
$DOB = $_POST['DOB']; 
$GPA = $_POST['GPA']; 
$height = $_POST['height']; 
$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$about = $_POST['about'];

$message = "Form details below.\n\n";  
function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);}

$message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$message .= "Graduation Year: ".clean_string($gradyear)."\n";
$message .= "High School: ".clean_string($hschool)."\n";
$message .= "Hometown: ".clean_string($hometown)."\n";
$message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($DOB)."\n";
$message .= "GPA: ".clean_string($GPA)."\n";
$message .= "Height: ".clean_string($height)."\n";
$message .= "Weight: ".clean_string($weight)."\n";
$message .= "About: ".clean_string($about)."\n";


/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $email_from"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
/* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
$file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
fclose($file); 

/* a boundary string */
$randomVal = md5(time()); 
$mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

/* Header for File Attachment */
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

/* Multipart Boundary above message */
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
"--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
$message . "\n\n"; 

/* Encoding file data */
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

/* Adding attchment-file to message*/
$message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
"Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
" name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
$data . "\n\n" . 
"--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);  
header("Location: http://myURL.com/contact.html");

?>
```

Comment: You can't narrow it down more than this?

Comment: You may want to review this example on the PHP website: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php. You're code is assuming a file is present. It's worth using `isset`, `in_array`, `empty` or a combination of these functions to ensure a file was sent and the `$_FILES` array is not empty. If it's empty (i.e. a file was not sent, skip reading the file...

Comment: remove the `@` sing from `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);` and add it into a variable: `$success = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);` and then `var_dump($success);` what does it says?

Answer (score 0):

You should check first that a file was indeed uploaded before manipulating the file:

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES)) {
//file manipulation...
}
```